# Looping over lines in a string in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to understand why this small piece of code does not work as expected.
I would expect it to print out "foo", but in fact what I get is

```
CL-USER> (stringloop)
null output T
 line output NIL

NIL
```

I expect I am using `do` wrong, but I've not be able to figure out what.

```
(defun stringloop ()
(with-input-from-string (s "foo" :index j )
  (do ((line (read-line s nil) ;; var init-form
         (read-line s nil))) ;; step=form
      ((null line) (progn (format t "null output ~a~% "(null line)) (format t "line output ~a~% " line))))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't put anything in the loop body. Your function reads a line (`"foo"`), does nothing with it, then reads another line (`nil`), your termination condition becomes true, and you print the null line.

Run this modified version to see what's happening:

```
     (defun stringloop ()
       (with-input-from-string (s "foo")
         (do ((line (read-line s nil) ;; var init-form
                    (read-line s nil))) ;; step=form
             ((null line) (format t "termination condition - line: ~s~% " line))
           (format t "in loop - line: ~s~%" line))))
```

Comment: Hi Angus. Thank you very much for the explanation. I'll ask if I have further questions.

Comment: Hi Angus. I see my mistake. From PCL "When the end-test-form evaluates to true, the result-forms are evaluated, and the value of the last result form is returned as the value of the DO expression." I somehow got the impression that the result-forms were evaluated at every step, but in fact are only evaluated at the last step, when the line is null. So my print condition should have been in the loop body, right?